# Connecting to a DO Postgres Cluster on .NET Core with a ca certificate via npgsql

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, digital-ocean, npgsql

I'm actually using ***DigitalOcean's Postgres cluster***. Managed to connect via DataGrip to the server with the credentials I have but I'm facing an auth issue on .NET Core. Apparently, you need to auth with the credentials given + the ca-certificate provided (DigitalOcean provides the CA).

```
services.AddDbContext<NozomiDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseNpgsql(mainDb
                        , builder =>
                        {
                            builder.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                            builder.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(certificates =>
                            {
                                var cert = new X509Certificate2("ca-certificate.crt");
                                certificates.Add(cert);
                            });
                        }
                    );
                    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(false);
                    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
                }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

After that, running the project results in:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

What am I doing wrong? Really apologise if this isn't enough.

Am on PG 11.4 by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server certificate is likely self-signed or cannot be validated for some reason. You can tell Npgsql to disable checking the server certificate by adding `Trust Server Certificate=true` on the connection string.

[See more in the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls).

Comment: DO allow you to download a certificate - is there something that can be done with that?

Comment: Yes, if you install those globally on your machine, Npgsql's validation will work on that. Or, as the docs say, you can register the `UserCertificateValidationCallback` callback on the connection to control validation yourself.

Comment: love SO... 2 years later, google brings me to this answer again to solve the problem again!